# Using Bootstrap to setup colored boxes in a set design, while being responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am doing an *about page* for a, rather troublesome, client. I am working within the Bootstrap 3.3 framework. As I hope it is evident from the picture below, the page is rather difficult to make **responsive**, which is has to be, while keeping the position of the colored boxes.

I have setup the text, without much trouble, but I simply have no idea how to manage the boxes.

**My question is** - How can I setup these boxes in a responsive manner, while keeping the design?

[image: About Page mockup]

Comment: So the overlapping boxes are the desired look? Do you have comps for different size devices?

Comment: Yes, the picture is how my client would like the page to look. I do not have any compositions, other than what bootstrap framework does for tablet and phone sizes.

Comment: Since this design you have is so drastically different than what a normal bootstrap design is, I would request comps or wireframes for this page. You'll have to make some major changes to bootstrap's design to get this look, so IMO need to get the tablet and mobile comps.